# error "cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier."

Tags: sql-server

I am receiving the error:

> Cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 655 and earlier.

I did some research and usually this error is found when SQL Server 2008 is being used and a `.mdf` file is from SQL Server 2012 is trying to be attached. In my case I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio attaching a `.mdf` file also from 2012 and I am still receiving this error.

Comment: SQL management studio may be 2012, but what version is the server  and instance that you're connected to running?

Comment: Check what SQL Server **engine version** is running : `SELECT @@Version` - the version of the Management Studio is for the most part irrelevant - the ***ENGINE*** must be the right version!

Comment: Okay thanks yeah the engine version running was 2008, how can I change that to 2012? because I have 2012 installed.